# Does the color of the pepper seeds correspond to its viability?

Tags: seeds, peppers

I cut open a organic Shishito pepper and noticed that its seeds had varying colors. It ranged from white, to brown, to black. How does the shade of color correspond to its viability? I'm planning on growing these seeds.

[image]